# Need regex to match the exact number of spaces found in a mask

Tags: regex, vb.net

So I'm writing a program to print music books based on files found. I already have the option of reading the tag finished but parsing file names is much faster so I decided to make it an option. The user will supply a mask similar to:

```
    (%year%) %album%\%track%. %artist% - %title%
```

So I need to create the regex with code. I have it almost finished but am having trouble with spaces. I need to be able to match the exact number of spaces supplied in the mask. Here is what I have so far:

```
    ^(?<track>[^.]+)\.[ ](?![ ])(?<artist>.+?)[ ](?![ ])-[ ](?![ ])(?<title>[^.]+)\.mp3$
```

The lookaheads work all work fine except for the one before the dash. Don't know why. It will allow more than a single space (but not 0 spaces). So what I need is something I can "plug in" to the mask for each space that I find and it will match only that space.

Comment: Ok, just tried a lookbehind for the space before the dash and lookahead for the space after the dash. That seems to work. Going to run some tests on it....

Comment: I think you copied the lookaround part wrong from my comment on the other question. It's supposed to be `(?<![ ])[ ]-[ ](?![ ])` (probably what you have tried now). The lookahead after the space will always succeed, because the next character has to be a hyphen anyway (which is never a space).

Answer (score 1):

## The Problem

The problem is with your regex named captures, which are collecting all non `.` characters. The `[^.]` character class also matches a space. So an expression like `\s{1}([^.]+)\s{2}\.` will allow:

```
 SomeTitle    .mp3
^^^^^^^^^^^^  
   SomeTitle  .mp3
  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The capture group will get the underlined section, including the underlined leading or trailing spaces. This essentially allows more spaces to exist in the source string then are desired. To fix this then you'd need to use a look ahead `(?!\s)` after every desired space match to ensure the next character captured by a character class won't be a space like `\s{1}(?!\s)([^.]+)\s{2}(?!\s).

## Solution

This regex will capture the track, artist, and title from a string in this format: `(%year%) %album%\%track%. %artist% - %title%`. To ensure the next character is not a space, then use `(?!\s)`. This is inserted a the end

`^\((?<year>[^)]*)\)\s{1}(?!\s)(?<album>[^\\]*)\\(?<track>[^.]*)\.\s{1}(?!\s)(?<artist>(?:(?!\s{1}-\s{1}).)+?[^\s])\s{1}-\s{1}(?!\s)(?<title>[^.]*?[^.\s])\.(?<ZeroLengthSpaceAfterDot>(?!\s))mp3`

[image]

In the image, Group 1 = year, group 2 = album, group 3 = track, group 4 = artist, group 5 = title, group 6 is the example of zero spaces

## VB.NET Code Example:

Input Text

```
(%year%) %album%\%track%. %artist% - %title%.mp3
(1971) Punk Kittens\1of3. Kittens - I Like cats.mp3
(1969) Muppet Show\2of3. Pigs - Pigs In Space. mp3
(1991) Foo Shivle\3of3. Snoop Dog - Just another brick in the pound.mp3
(2009) Space Race\3of3. Sir Space Alot -  Too many Spaces.mp3
```

Code sample

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("^\((?<year>[^)]*)\)\s{1}(?!\s)(?<album>[^\\]*)\\(?<track>[^.]*)\.\s{1}(?!\s)(?<artist>(?:(?!\s{1}-\s{1}).)+?[^\s])\s{1}-\s{1}(?!\s)(?<title>[^.]*?[^.\s])\.(?<ZeroLengthSpaceAfterDot>(?!\s))mp3",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

Matches

```
$matches Array:
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => (%year%) %album%\%track%. %artist% - %title%.mp3
        [1] => (1971) Punk Kittens\1of3. Kittens - I Like cats.mp3
        [2] => (1991) Foo Shivle\3of3. Snoop Dog - Just another brick in the pound.mp3
    )

[year] => Array
    (
        [0] => %year%
        [1] => 1971
        [2] => 1991
    )


[album] => Array
    (
        [0] => %album%
        [1] => Punk Kittens
        [2] => Foo Shivle
    )


[track] => Array
    (
        [0] => %track%
        [1] => 1of3
        [2] => 3of3
    )


[artist] => Array
    (
        [0] => %artist%
        [1] => Kittens
        [2] => Snoop Dog
    )

[title] => Array
    (
        [0] => %title%
        [1] => I Like cats
        [2] => Just another brick in the pound
    )


[ZeroLengthSpaceAfterDot] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
    )


)
```

## Space options

- `\s` or `\s{1}` match one space
- `\s(?!\s)` match one space and ensure the character after the space is not a space.
- `\s*` match zero or more spaces
- `\s{2,}` match two or more spaces
- `(?!\s)` ensure the next character is not a space
- `(?!\s{6})` ensure the next six characters are not all spaces

Comment: I am using Rubular for my testing and it is still matching more than 1 space (but not zero spaces) so the mask: "(%year%) %album%\%track%. %artist% - %title%" is not the same as: "(%year%) %album%\%track%. %artist%  -  %title%" (2 spaces before and after the dash) but it still matches

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?<track>[^.]+)\. (?! )(?<artist>.+?[^ ]) (?! )- (?! )(?<title>[^.]+)\.mp3$
                  ^                       ^      ^
```

Specify the length of any of the three space-holders `^` above to match the mask.

I tested the above regex pattern using RegexBuddy. The outcome is as in the screenshot below:-

[image]

Comment: Yes. I tried this. This is basically the same thing I have in my question except I enclosed my spaces in brackets. It will not work for the space before the dash. I found that enclosing the space in a lookbehind and then a lookahead seems to work but I am still testing. The regex looks like this: ^(?<track>[^.]+)\.[ ](?![ ])(?<artist>.+?)(?<! ) (?![ ])-(?<! ) (?![ ])(?<title>[^.]+)\.mp3$

Comment: Note the artist group, I added `[^ ]` right before the closing bracket to become `(?<artist>.+?[^ ])`. This will make sure any extra spaces between the artist name and the _space-dash_ won't become part of the artist name group.

Comment: I modified your character class `[ ]` to become just a space was for clarity for me when testing. I don't know your reason for making it as a class if you only want to detect for spaces.